# Plotting contour circles in mathematica for a given function value and radius

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have an arbitrary function of f(x) with each discrete x value. The value of the function is circularly symmetrical. I want to plot those circles in mathematica using x as radius and values of f(x) as the height of this plot. Can you help me with that please? Also I don't know how to use lists of numbers as an input to plot discrete circles in 3D.
I tried

```
Plot3D[f*Exp[I*phi], {x, 0, 10}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

or

```
ContourPlot[f*Exp[I*phi], {x, 0, 10}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Nothing shows up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
f[x_]:=x^2;
Show[
  Map[(x=#;ParametricPlot3D[{x*Cos[phi],x*Sin[phi],f[x]},{phi,0,2Pi}])&,Range[1,10]],
  PlotRange->All
]
```

where I arbitrarily picked an f[x] and used a list of {1,2,3,...10} for discrete x values. You could replace that `Range[1,10]` with something like `{5,7,3/2,1.8}` if you had a specific list of numbers that you wanted to use for x.

The Map function created a ParametricPlot3D for each of the discrete values of x and then the Show combined all those into a single plot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this and works. Can you help me with the contour plots also how can I add a color bar to that?

Comment: Try `f[x_,y_]:=x^2+y^2;
ContourPlot[f[x,y],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4},Contours->{1,4,9,16},ContourLabels->True]` Look at the documentation for `ContourPlot` and click on the orange Details and Options and read each line in that. Maybe that will help you understand this and see what you need to do next.